# d3js program produces nice browser image, horrible conversion to png

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've got a d3 charting program from one of the d3 examples and it looks great in the browser.

I grab the associated SVG via...

```
 var svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
```

and eventually copy it to a .svg file on my Mac. The QuickLook previewing system renders this with x/y axis that are much thicker than the original, and the CloudConvert service makes a png where the quality is even worse - the lines overlap with the axis labels.

I have the standard axis css rules...

```
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

so I'm at a loss to understand why the renderings are done differently.

Comment: Does serializeToString make use of CSS informations, which are not defined in the xml tag itself?

Comment: See https://github.com/NYTimes/svg-crowbar.

Comment: I don't know if it does include the CSS info, but I presumed that the D3 renderer would use this information to produce a series of SVG commands, which were then used to draw the on screen image.

It's that instruction stream I thought the "svg" DOM element was extracting.